# data.table: count rows within time moving window

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(col1 = c('B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), col2 = c("2015-03-06 01:37:57", "2015-03-06 01:39:57", "2015-03-06 01:45:28", "2015-03-06 02:31:44", "2015-03-06 03:55:45", "2015-03-06 04:01:40"))
```

For each row I want to count number of rows with same values of 'col1' and time within window of past 10 minutes before time of this row(include)

I run next code:

```
df$col2 <- as_datetime(df$col2)
window = 10L
(counts = setDT(df)[.(t1=col2-window*60L, t2=col2), on=.((col2>=t1) & (col2<=t2)), 
                     .(counts=.N), by=col1]$counts)

df[, counts := counts]
```

and got next mistake:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df), .(t1 = col2 - window * 60L, t2 = col2), : Column(s) [(col2] not found in x
```

I want result like next:

```
col1    col2              counts
B   2015-03-06 01:37:57     1
A   2015-03-06 01:39:57     1
A   2015-03-06 01:45:28     2
B   2015-03-06 02:31:44     1
B   2015-03-06 03:55:45     1
B   2015-03-06 04:01:40     2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df[.(col1 = col1, t1 = col2 - gap * 60L, t2 = col2)
   , on = .(col1, col2 >= t1, col2 <= t2)
   , .(counts = .N), by = .EACHI][, (2) := NULL][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    col1                col2 counts
> 1:    B 2015-03-06 01:37:57      1
> 2:    A 2015-03-06 01:39:57      1
> 3:    A 2015-03-06 01:45:28      2
> 4:    B 2015-03-06 02:31:44      1
> 5:    B 2015-03-06 03:55:45      1
> 6:    B 2015-03-06 04:01:40      2
> ```

A couple of notes about your approach:

- You don't need `setDT` because you already constructed `df` with `data.table(...)`.
- You `on`-statement isn't specified correctly: you need to separate the join conditions with a `,` and not with a `&`. For example: `on = .(col1, col2 >= t1, col2 <= t2)`
- Use `by = .EACHI` to get the result for each row.

---

An alternative approach:

```
df[, counts := .SD[.(col1 = col1, t1 = col2 - gap * 60L, t2 = col2)
                   , on = .(col1, col2 >= t1, col2 <= t2)
                   , .N, by = .EACHI]$N][]
```

which gives the same result.

Comment: sometimes data.table solutions blows my mind completely.