# data.table: calculate statistics of rows time within time moving window

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.table(col1 = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), col2 = c("2015-03-06 01:37:57", "2015-03-06 01:39:57", "2015-03-06 01:45:28", "2015-03-06 02:31:44", "2015-03-06 03:55:45", "2015-03-06 04:01:40"))
```

For each row I want to calculate standard deviation of time(col2) of rows with same values of 'col1' and time within window of past 10 minutes before time of this row(include)

I use next approach:

```
df$col2 <- as_datetime(df$col2)
gap <- 10L
df[, feat1 := .SD[.(col1 = col1, t1 = col2 - gap * 60L, t2 = col2)
                   , on = .(col1, col2 >= t1, col2 <= t2)
                   , .(sd_time = sd(as.numeric(col2))), by = .EACHI]$sd_time][]
```

as result I see only NA values instead of values in seconds

For example for third row (col="A" and col2 = "2015-03-06 01:45:28")
I have calculated manually by next way:

```
v <- c("2015-03-06 01:37:57", "2015-03-06 01:39:57", "2015-03-06 01:45:28")
v <- as_datetime(v)
sd(v) = 233.5815
```

Comment: `sd` applied to a vector of length 1 is `NA` your granularity is such that all your vectors of dates are of length 1.

Comment: Max Ft, in a lot cases you right, but for col1='A' and col2 = "2015-03-06 01:45:28" you is wrong, for this row also NA, so I think need to modify data.table request

Comment: Based on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49358601/2204410) to your previous question you could do: `df[.(col1 = col1, t1 = col2 - gap * 60L, t2 = col2), on = .(col1, col2 >= t1, col2 <= t2)][, .(feat1 = sd(as.numeric(col2))), .(col1, col2.1)]`, but that won't get you a meaningful answer as it either returns `NA` because you can't calculate the `sd` of one number (as @MaxFt said) or `0` because when you have more than one value, they will be the same.

Comment: @Jaap, you are wrong - please analyze manual calculation for row with col1='A' and col2 = "2015-03-06 01:45:28" : v <- c("2015-03-06 01:37:57", "2015-03-06 01:39:57", "2015-03-06 01:45:28"); v <- as_datetime(v); sd(v) = 233.5815

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure `data.table` solution:

```
df[,col3:=as.numeric(col2)]
df[, feat1 := {
  d <- data$col3 - col3
  sd(data$col3[col1 == data$col1 & d <= 0 & d >= -gap * 60L])
},
by = list(col3, col1)]
```

Another way to loop over all combinations of col1, col2 with `mapply`:

```
df[,col3:=as.numeric(col2)]

df[, feat1:=mapply(Date = col3,ID = col1, function(Date, ID) {
  DateVect=df[col1 == ID,col3]
  d <- DateVect - Date
  sd(DateVect[d <= 0 & d >= -gap * 60L])})][]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two alternative `data.table` solutions (variations on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358274/data-table-count-rows-within-time-moving-window/49358601#49358601)):

```
# option 1
df[.(col1 = col1, t1 = col2, t2 = col2 + gap * 60L)
   , on = .(col1, col2 >= t1, col2 <= t2)
   , .(col1, col2 = x.col2, times = as.numeric(t1))
   ][, .(feat1 = sd(times))
     , by = .(col1, col2)]

# option 2
df[, feat1 := .SD[.(col1 = col1, t1 = col2, t2 = col2 + gap * 60L)
                  , on = .(col1, col2 >= t1, col2 <= t2)
                  , .(col1, col2 = x.col2, times = as.numeric(t1))
                  ][, .(sd_times = sd(times))
                    , by = .(col1, col2)]$sd_times][]
```

which both give:

> ```
>    col1                col2     feat1
> 1:    A 2015-03-06 00:37:57        NA
> 2:    A 2015-03-06 00:39:57  84.85281
> 3:    A 2015-03-06 00:45:28 233.58153
> 4:    B 2015-03-06 01:31:44        NA
> 5:    B 2015-03-06 02:55:45        NA
> 6:    B 2015-03-06 03:01:40 251.02291
> ```

Comment: your solutions looks like correct - but very strange results - I asked about window of past time from current row - not next as your output : you incorrect because feat1 = 233.5815 for third row - not first as you, also feat1 = 251.0229 for six row - not for five as you. Please make correct your data.table.query.

Comment: shortly telling, yor query looks like with window in previous 10 minutes, but output give deviations with window in future 10 minutes, which strange for me

Comment: @evgeniiershenko Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the code. HTH